# jQuery mobile image slide freezing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile, jquery-mobile

My mobile website: http://mobile.jshjohnson.com  has an image slider which works fine on initial load, however if you submit the form at the bottom then go back to the original page, the image slider freezes. Does anyone know how I would go about stopping this happening? Is it just a bug in jQuery mobile?

Josh

Edit: Sorry, I am experiencing this on iOS

Comment: I'm not sure how you're using the back button, but I does mess it up. Try making it a link to your homepage

Comment: I tried it on iphone simulator ios 5 and it worked fine after going back to index